# How I can open another ViewController in a Partial Table (Infinite Scroller)

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, viewcontroller, infinite-scroll

I'm following the next example code to do a infinite scroller in a TableView.

https://github.com/Abizern/PartialTable/blob/master/PartialTable/TableViewController.m

My problem is that, in this source code I don't know how to open another ViewController when I click in some row.

I think that I need this to open it:

```
Manage *man = [manages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
DetailManageViewController *vcc = [[DetailManageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailManageViewController" bundle:nil];
vcc.manage = man;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcc animated:YES];
```

But I don't know where to put in the source code of the example.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the code in `UITableViewDelegate` method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

For more information see documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:).

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `UITableViewDelegate` protocol in the class you want to handle the row taps.

Then you would set the `tableView.delegate = self` (if the table view is in that class, otherwise an object that implements the protocol).

And finaly when you implement the protocol, you should add method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` that will handle the taps. There you put your code to open a new view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Add `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` in your interface. Set `tableView.dataSource = self;` and `tableView.delegate = self;` at the place where `tableView` is created. If your `ViewController` is a `NavigationController`, you can push the new `viewController` in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      Manage *man = [manages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      DetailManageViewController *vcc = [[DetailManageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailManageViewController" bundle:nil];
      vcc.manage = man;
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:vcc animated:YES];
}
```